# Exporting forecast data from darts

Tags: python, pytorch, u8darts

I am trying to export the forecasts I made with Pytorch models in darts library to some exchangeable format like XLS or CSV.

Is it somehow possible to export the predictions from the Timeseries class? How can I specify output format?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Forecasts in Darts are nothing but regular `TimeSeries` objects and a `TimeSeries` is internally represented as a `pandas.DataFrame`.

You can access this `DataFrame` using `series.pd_dataframe()` (to get a copy of the `DataFrame`) or `series._df` directly if you want to avoid copying the `DataFrame` to save it. Be careful in the latter case however, as modifying the `DataFrame` in place will break the `TimeSeries` immutability.

You can then use any method you'd like to save pandas dataframes, e.g. `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()` or `pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle()`. You can have a look at [this article on Medium](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-best-format-to-save-pandas-data-414dca023e0d) to see a comparison of a couple different formats' performances for saving and loading dataframes.

Comment: It saved entire data into xarray object into pandas (e.g. "<xarray.DataArray ()>\narray(8.25364938)\nCoordinates:\n    datetime   datetime64[ns] 2016-06-01\n    component  <U5 'sales'\n    quantile   float64 0.1")

Comment: The second proposed option of series._df does not seem valid (any more ?). I am with darts 0.24.0

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `.to_csv()`, `.to_json()` or `.to_pickle()` on your time series.

See https://unit8co.github.io/darts/generated_api/darts.timeseries.html.